# map inside macro injected in Ecto from

Tags: macros, ecto

from these two macros properly defined in a module

```
 defmacro binary(key) do
    quote do
        [
             fragment("some fragment", unquote(key)),
             fragment("some fragment", unquote(key))
        ]
    end
  end



defmacro mapbin(key) do
        quote do
            %{
               "1" =>   fragment("some fragment same as above", unquote(key)),
                "2" =>  fragment("some fragment same as above", unquote(key))
            }
        end
      end
```

this works

```
 from u in Table, select: binary("key")
```

but not this

```
from u in Table, select: mapbin("key")
```

What is the problem with the map in the macro ?

the message is compile error
`%{"1" => fragment("", ""),...}` is not a valid query expression.

Answer (score 0):

it was a bug in ecto

it has been fixed

see https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1936